# Installing ncnn on Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, yolo, onnx

I have trained a custom YOLOX model on google colab and want to convert it from .onnx to .ncnn.

I'm using the following as directions: https://github.com/Megvii-BaseDetection/YOLOX/blob/main/demo/ncnn/cpp/README.md#step4

Step 1 requires building ncnn with directions: https://github.com/Tencent/ncnn/wiki/how-to-build#build-for-macos

The directions give instructions for building on different devices.

My question:  Which instructions should I use to build ncnn on Google Colab?